# Overloading Operator [] to Accept Range

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to overload operator[] to accept 2 `int`'s, so that the user will be able to specify a range of indices like so:

```
MyClass[1:5]
```

I tried this:

```
void operator[](const int, const int);
```

with the hope that I would be able to use it with comma:

```
MyClass[1,5]
```

but I get a compiler error:

```
too many parameters for this operator function
```

Is there a way that I can achieve such behaviour?

Thanks

EDIT:
I was hoping the operator would do something like so:

```
struct MyClass
{
    vector<std::string> data;
    void operator[] (const int start, const int end)
    {
        for(int index = start; index <= end; index++)
        {
            cout << data[index] << '\n';
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible.

You need to pick a different syntax, e.g:

- `MyClass(1,5)` - overloaded `operator()`.
- `MyClass.foo(1,5)` - a member function.
- `MyClass[{1,5}]` - overloaded `operator[]` with a parameter of class type, which has a constructor that accepts 2 parameters.

Comment: I am trying to implement your last suggestion (passing class as argument) and somehow things aren't working as expected. would you care to give a simple example of how the declaration and definition of such solution would work? Thanks!

Comment: @SAR Something like `struct Foo {int a, b;};`, then `void operator[](Foo param){/*use param.a and param.b here*/}`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's so simple, and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example std::initializer_list as an argument.

For example

```
T & operator []( const std::initializer_list<size_t> & );
const T & operator []( const std::initializer_list<size_t> & ) const;
```

or just like

```
T operator []( const std::initializer_list<size_t> & ) const;
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad from Moscow, could you give an example of how you'd implement the oprator?

Comment: @SAR Show at first what you are going to do with this operator and the corresponding class where the operator should be defined.